# Body recognition in EmguCV/OpenCV (Tracking person in video)

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, tracking, emgucv

I am trying to recognize the person in video (not by his face but by his body). What I have done so far now is to find the HOG,HS and RGB histograms of a person and compare it with all other person to find him.

I am using EmguCV but OpenCV's help will also be appreciated.

**HOG is Calculated using**

```
        Size imageSize = new Size(64, 16);
        Size blockSize = new Size(16, 16);
        Size blockStride = new Size(16, 8);
        Size cellSize = new Size(8, 8);

        HOGDescriptor hog = new HOGDescriptor(imageSize, blockSize, blockStride, cellSize);

        float[] hogs = hog.Compute(image);
```

**Code to Calculate HS Histograms (Same method is used for RGB)**

```
        Image<Gray, byte>[] channels = hsvImage.Copy().Split();
        Image<Gray, byte> hue = channels[0];
        Image<Gray, byte> sat = channels[1];

        dh.Calculate<byte>(new Image<Gray, byte>[] { hue }, true, null);
        dh2.Calculate<byte>(new Image<Gray, byte>[] { sat }, true, null);

        float[] huehist = dh.GetBinValues();
        float[] sathist = dh2.GetBinValues();
```

**Calculating distance of 2 histograms using**

```
        double distance = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < hist1.Length; i++)
        {
            distance += Math.Abs(hist1[i] - hist2[i]);
        }
        return distance;
```

**What is happening**

I am trying to track a selected person from video feed. and the person can move from camera to camera.
The body of **personA** is extracted from the video frame, whose HOG,HS,RGB histograms are calculated and stored... then from next frame the histograms of all detected persons are calculated and matched with the histograms of **personA** the most matched histogram (with minimum distance) is considered as the same person (personA)... so it is continued to track that person...

**Problem**

- Accuracy is not good (sometimes it tells 2 people, with very different colored cloths, same)

**Suggestions**

- What should I change/remove
- Should I calculate histograms using **CvInvoke.CalcHist(...);** instead of dense histograms for HS and RGB
- Should I normalize histograms before calculating distances.
- Is this normalization method good? (every value **minus** mean of array)
- Or should I try something else.

**Any kind of help/suggestion will be HIGHLY APPRECIATED** if any more info is needed then please comment.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on the same project, we have same idea of work, i have solutions for this problem.

**Solution 1:** 
after detection of the person crop the detected person extract features, save those features, next them time you wish to track the person extract feature form the frame compare them, I have wrote the whole algorithm

**Solution 2** 
(incase you want to speed up) find the region of the person convert to binary save edges convert the whole frame to binary, find human body region

I have find other tricks for accuracy please contact me on email i have problem writing code we might work together find the best solution

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Soliciting contact by email is not acceptable here; ideally, an answer should contain everything that is needed to solve the OP's question. Feel free to add a link to your code if it is open source.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply. I am already working as your solution1 and i would definitely try solution2. And it would be great if we could work together.

Comment: Welcome Nabeel, I am working on a single camera, i have used SVM to store human body details but their is a little problem i couldn't find contour area of a human body:
Rectangle[] reg; 
 des.SetSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor.GetDefaultPeopleDetector());
                reg = des.DetectMultiScale(image);
this return rectangle which contain lill amount of background, i wish to have only human body area.